# How to find modules used in initrd?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, initramfs, initrd

Is there a way to see all the kernel modules/drivers put in the `initrd`/`intramfs`?

Comment: See [`lsinitramfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/lsinitramfs.8.html).

Comment: But good luck running `lsinitramfs` on a recent initramfs :-(.

Comment: @StephenKitt: what's the problem?

Comment: @Ipor from the manpage, “`lsinitramfs` cannot deal with  multiple-segmented  initramfs  images”; and many initramfs images are multiple-segmented nowadays.

Comment: ... although to be fair many of my problems appear to have been caused by having `zutils` installed — its `zcat` seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack and see the contents. Example:

```
mkdir /tmp/initrd
cd /tmp/initrd
/usr/lib/dracut/skipcpio /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img | gunzip -c | cpio -idmv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to regenerate your initrfamfs in the process, you can run `update-initramfs -v`. The verbose option will list all of the modules being included in the output. I found this the easiest option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just noted that `mc` (Midnight Commander) can navigate my initramfs (didn't check more than this). Maybe this could be enough for you.